# TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() and TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes() always return 0 in Nexus 5x

Tags: android, android-trafficstats

I am trying to fetch mobile data usage using TrafficStats.

Example:

mobileDataUsage = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() +TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()

totalUsage =  TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()

In few devices it is working absolutely fine. In **Nexus 5X** I am getting totalUsage but mobileDataUsage is always 0, `TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()` and `TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()` always return 0.

Answer (score 2):

You most probably are seeing the issue described at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78924 .

The [docs for TrafficStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) says the bytes returned *"always increases monotonically since device boot"*, but that is indeed not the case for at least Android 5-7. Often the methods return 0 and then suddenly start counting from the number they used to have.